# HTTP post with JSON payload body containing an empty line using cURL

Tags: c#, json, curl, http-post

I'm sending a json payload to a server backend (.NET .ashx (c#) handler)  via cURL as follows:

```
curl -X POST -d@filename.txt http://localhost:49797/Handler.ashx -H "Content-Type:application/json"
```

The JSON (sitting in filename.txt) has a blank line in it (if any of you recognise it its from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html which I am using to verify my AWS4 signing code)

```
{ "expiration": "2015-12-30T12:00:00.000Z",
  "conditions": [
   {"bucket": "sigv4examplebucket"},
    ["starts-with", "$key", "user/user1/"],
    {"acl": "public-read"},
    {"success_action_redirect":"http://sigv4examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html"},
    ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"],
    {"x-amz-meta-uuid": "14365123651274"},
    {"x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"},
    ["starts-with", "$x-amz-meta-tag", ""],

    {"x-amz-credential": "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE/20151229/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request"},
    {"x-amz-algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"},
    {"x-amz-date": "20151229T000000Z" }
  ]
}
```

I'm reading the payload as follows on the server:

```
private string getPayloadString(HttpRequest Request)
    {
        string documentContents;
        using (Stream receiveStream = Request.InputStream)
        {
            using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                documentContents = readStream.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        return documentContents;
    }
```

When I inspect 'documentContents' in visual studio I basically get a string as follows:

```
{ "expiration": "2015-12-30T12:00:00.000Z",  "conditions": [    {"bucket": "sigv4examplebucket"},    ["starts-with", "$key", "user/user1/"],    {"acl": "public-read"},    {"success_action_redirect": "http://sigv4examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html"},    ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"],    {"x-amz-meta-uuid": "14365123651274"},    {"x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"},    ["starts-with", "$x-amz-meta-tag", ""],    {"x-amz-credential": "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE/20151229/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request"},    {"x-amz-algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"},    {"x-amz-date": "20151229T000000Z" }  ]}
```

Which in turn when I base64Encode it doesn't match the expected value on the AWS page (it does match up if I literally hard code the string in my server code before encoding it)

My question(s) are

1. Am I losing the blankline the way I am reading the payload? If so how should I do it?
2. Is cURL not sending the data exactly like it is in my txt file?
3. Is it just  Visual studio stripping it out when I look at it in the text visualizer?

Thanks, this signature not matching error from AWS is wrecking my head!

Comment: My guess is that some of the characters being converted to base64 has a different value when decoded because I encountered that problem from time to time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using --data-binary with curl to maintain the line breaks.

From here https://ec.haxx.se/http-post.html

> POSTing binary When reading from a file, -d will strip out carriage
>   return and newlines. Use --data-binary if you want curl to read and
>   use the given file in binary exactly as given:
>
> curl --data-binary @filename http://example.com/